# Accessing a JHipster application (running in dev mode) from a remote machine

Tags: angular, spring-boot, configuration, jhipster, remote-access

I have a JHipster Application running in the dev mode.
It is using spring boot in the back-end and Angular 6 in the front end.

To run the application on my local machine, I am using "npm start" or "yarn start" to start the client side server and to start the back-end server, I am running the springboot application from the Eclipse IDE.
This setup works fine on my local machine.

But what changes should I make in the application to access it from a remote machine?
I tried modifying parent-dir\webpack\webpack.dev.js to make it happen but it didn't work.
I had read somewhere that remote access is possible by running "ng serve" but as far as I know, JHipster does not support this command.

Below is the webpack.dev.js file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const SimpleProgressWebpackPlugin = require('simple-progress-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const path = require('path');
const sass = require('sass');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'development';

module.exports = (options) => webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './target/www',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console',
                '/auth'
            ],
            target: `http${options.tls ? 's' : ''}://127.0.0.1:8080`,
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: options.tls,
            headers: { host: 'localhost:9000' }
        }],
        stats: options.stats,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        }
    },
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('target/www'),
        filename: 'app/[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: 'tslint-loader',
            exclude: ['node_modules', new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [
                'angular2-template-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'cache-loader',
                    options: {
                      cacheDirectory: path.resolve('target/cache-loader')
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'thread-loader',
                    options: {
                        // there should be 1 cpu for the fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
                        workers: require('os').cpus().length - 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        transpileOnly: true,
                        happyPackMode: true
                    }
                },
                'angular-router-loader'
            ],
            exclude: ['node_modules']
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }],
            exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: { implementation: sass }
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }]
    },
    stats: process.env.JHI_DISABLE_WEBPACK_LOGS ? 'none' : options.stats,
    plugins: [
        process.env.JHI_DISABLE_WEBPACK_LOGS
            ? null
            : new SimpleProgressWebpackPlugin({
                format: options.stats === 'minimal' ? 'compact' : 'expanded'
              }),
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9000,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:9060'
            },
            socket: {
                clients: {
                    heartbeatTimeout: 60000
                }
            }
        }, {
            reload: false
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/webapp')
        ),
        new writeFilePlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
            utils.root('src/test'),
        ]),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            title: 'JHipster',
            contentImage: path.join(__dirname, 'logo-jhipster.png')
        })
    ].filter(Boolean),
    mode: 'development'
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, webpack dev server listens on 127.0.0.1, you must configure it to listen on 0.0.0.0.

Edit `webpack/webpack.dev.js` and set host to 0.0.0.0:

```
devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
```

Comment: Thanks Gaël. It means a lot.

Comment: I am able to access the homepage from the remote machine but while logging from the user login page, it is not able to access the backend API. Is there any more changes required in the webpack.dev.js file? I have added an unedited version of the file in the question. Thanks

Comment: Have you started the java app? The webpack dev server proxifies all api calls to the java backend, so as long as webpack can be reached and the java backend runs it should work.

Comment: My app fails b/c this fails also - GET http://localhost:9060/sockjs-node/info?t=1551468626449